# How to add new textfield dynamically whenever click on Add Button

Tags: ios, objective-c

just now i created text field dynamically,when i was clicked on button
my code is :

```
-(void)clickonAdd
{
     CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(18, 350,309,35.0);
     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
     textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
     textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
     textField.placeholder = @"Select Item List";
     textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
     textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
     textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
     textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
     textField.contentVerticalAlignment =UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
     textField.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

now i want to add more textfield with different positions,when clicked on same button...can u please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: try this one...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889101/changing-position-of-text-fields-which-was-created-dynamically-while-clicking-on/35891743#35891743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    CGFloat y;
    CGFloat x;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    y = 0;
    x = 0;
}

-(void)clickButtonAdd
{
    UITextField *textField;
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,100,30);
    textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    x  = x + 120;
    y =  y + 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do like

**For Multiple textfield**

```
float x = 20;

float y = 40; 

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 UITextfield *textField = [[UITextfield alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,200,30)];
textfield.tag = i;

// add your code here 

 [self.view  addSubview:textField];

// if you want to change the y position of every textfield, change y coordinates
y = y+50;
 // if you want to change the x position of every textfield, change x coordinates
x = x+50;

}
```

**single textfield**

we can do it multiple ways.

**Choice-1**

```
@interface SettingsViewController ()
{
 // create two float values for x and y
 CGFloat y;
 CGFloat x;
  UITextField *textField;
}
```

on your viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

   y = 0;
   x = 0;
   CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(x, y,309,35.0);
  textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
 textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
 textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
 textField.placeholder = @"Select Item List";
 textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
 textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
 textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
 textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
 textField.contentVerticalAlignment =UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
 textField.delegate = self;
 [self.view addSubview:textField];

 // hide your textfield here
 textField.hidden  = YES;

}
```

on button action

```
-(void)clickonAdd
{
  textField.hidden  = NO;
  x  = x + 200;
  y =  y + 35;
  textField.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 309,35);
```

Comment: thq..Anbu.Karthik...for your valuable answer..but my concern is only one text field will be created when i clicked on button...i tried above like this i am getting continuosly "i" value text fields in once clicked on button

Comment: i have one button action...When i click on that button,only one text field will be create at one time..again i clicked on same button another text field will be create below the previously created text field...like this when ever i clicked on same button text field will be created each time...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
-(void)clickonAdd:(CGRect)aFrame
{
     CGRect textfieldFrame = aFrame;
     // Rest of the code...
}
```

And called it by `[self clickonAdd:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)]` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using UITableView. You'll need table view, where each table view cell just keeps UITextField.

Then in `clickonAdd` method you'll just need to add new cell into table view.

```
-(void) clickonAdd {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.textFieldsTableView  numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *newTextFieldIdxPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow: numberOfRows inSection:0];
    [self.textFieldsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newTextFieldIdxPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```